# Login to Salesforce SOAP API with .NET

Tags: soap-api, integration, exception, login, .net

At the moment I'm merely trying to achieve authentication and some very basic things, but I keep stumbling upon the same exception.

I have inserted both the `CallOptions` and the `LoginScopeHeader` as nulls to the login (line 55) since it's what I've seen people do in the docs. I also went to see the docs and I saw that those two parameters don't really provide me with any value since they're for org namespace, portalId, etc. Nonetheless, that's where the exception is thrown.

On the one hand, I have thought that I might be configuring headers wrong, since I'm not really specifying any url or anything, but on the other I thought that that's specified in the specific WSDL, right?

As you will see the code is as is in the documentation, except a couple of calls that required more parameters.

In any case, any help is appreciated! Thanks :=)

***Exception***

```
{"There was an error in serializing one of the headers in message loginRequest: 'Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).\r\nerror CS0030: Cannot convert type 'ForceConsole.PartnerSOAP.ListViewRecordColumn[]' to 'ForceConsole.PartnerSOAP.ListViewRecordColumn'\r\nerror CS0030: Cannot convert type 'ForceConsole.PartnerSOAP.ListViewRecordColumn[]' to 'ForceConsole.PartnerSOAP.ListViewRecordColumn'\r\nerror CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ForceConsole.PartnerSOAP.ListViewRecordColumn' to 'ForceConsole.PartnerSOAP.ListViewRecordColumn[]'\r\nerror CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ForceConsole.PartnerSOAP.ListViewRecordColumn' to 'ForceConsole.PartnerSOAP.ListViewRecordColumn[]'\r\n'.  Please see InnerException for more details."}
```

***Code***

```
namespace ForceConsole
{
    using ForceConsole.PartnerSOAP;
    using System;
    using System.ServiceModel;

    class Program
    {
        private static SoapClient loginClient; // for login endpoint
        private static SoapClient client; // for API endpoint
        private static SessionHeader header;
        private static EndpointAddress endpoint;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program sample = new Program();
            sample.run();
        }

        public void run()
        {
            // Make a login call 
            if (login())
            {
                // Log out
                logout();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private bool login()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter username: ");
            string username = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter password: ");
            string password = Console.ReadLine();

            // Create a SoapClient specifically for logging in
            loginClient = new SoapClient();

            // (combine pw and token if necessary)
            LoginResult lr;
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nLogging in...\n");
                lr = loginClient.login(null, null, username, password); //TODO
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Write the fault message to the console 
                Console.WriteLine("An unexpected error has occurred: " + e.Message);

                // Write the stack trace to the console 
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                return false;
            }

            // Check if the password has expired 
            if (lr.passwordExpired)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error has occurred. Your password has expired.");
                return false;
            }

            /** Once the client application has logged in successfully, it will use
             * the results of the login call to reset the endpoint of the service
             * to the virtual server instance that is servicing your organization
             */

            // On successful login, cache session info and API endpoint info
            endpoint = new EndpointAddress(lr.serverUrl);

            /** The sample client application now has a cached EndpointAddress
            * that is pointing to the correct endpoint. Next, the sample client
            * application sets a persistent SOAP header that contains the
            * valid sessionId for our login credentials. To do this, the sample
            * client application creates a new SessionHeader object. Add the session 
            * ID returned from the login to the session header
            */
            header = new SessionHeader();
            header.sessionId = lr.sessionId;

            // Create and cache an API endpoint client
            client = new SoapClient("Soap", endpoint);

            printUserInfo(lr, lr.serverUrl);

            // Return true to indicate that we are logged in, pointed  
            // at the right URL and have our security token in place. 
            return true;
        }

        private void printUserInfo(LoginResult lr, String authEP)
        {
            try
            {
                GetUserInfoResult userInfo = lr.userInfo;

                Console.WriteLine("\nLogging in ...\n");
                Console.WriteLine("UserID: " + userInfo.userId);
                Console.WriteLine("User Full Name: " +
                    userInfo.userFullName);
                Console.WriteLine("User Email: " +
                    userInfo.userEmail);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("SessionID: " +
                    lr.sessionId);
                Console.WriteLine("Auth End Point: " +
                    authEP);
                Console.WriteLine("Service End Point: " +
                    lr.serverUrl);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An unexpected error has occurred: " + e.Message +
                    " Stack trace: " + e.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        private void logout()
        {
            try
            {
                client.logout(header, null); //TODO
                Console.WriteLine("Logged out.");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Write the fault message to the console 
                Console.WriteLine("An unexpected error has occurred: " + e.Message);

                // Write the stack trace to the console 
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into the **"Cannot convert type 'X.Y.ListViewRecordColumn[]' to 'X.Y.ListViewRecordColumn'"** error [previously](http://www.fishofprey.com/2014/10/importing-salesforce-winter-15-partner.html). This started happening in Winter '15 (v32.0) when the ListViewRecord complex type started including an unbound collection of ListViewRecordColumn records.

The problem will be the `XmlArrayItemAttribute` that is associated with the `records` property in the C# class that is generated from the WSDL.

You need to change it from:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("columns", typeof(ListViewRecordColumn), IsNullable=false)]
```

to:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("columns", typeof(ListViewRecordColumn[]), IsNullable=false)]
```

Note the additional `[]` in appended to the typeof statement.

See also:

- Knowledge Article : ["Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1)" is returned when .Net integration tries to parse the Enterprise WSDL version 32.0](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000205824&language=en_US&type=1)